# What is the cardinality of the set of prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{Q}|=\aleph_0$ but which is the cardinal of $|\mathbb{P}|$? since there is [no formula for primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes), then I can conclude that there is not bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ and so $|\mathbb{P}|\ne\aleph_0$?

Comment: $\aleph$ is often the notation for a general [well-ordered] cardinal or for the cardinal of the continuum. The cardinality of $\mathbb N$ is denoted $\aleph_0$.

Comment: There no practical/nice/closed-form/easily-computable formula for the $n-$th prime, but it's easy to program an algorithm for that. Furthermore, any infinite subset of the naturals can be put in bijective correspondence with the naturals.

Comment: Just because there is no **formula** for a bijection does not mean there isn't a bijection. The common misunderstanding that a lot of people have is that functions need to have "formulas" or "equations". This is not always the case. Check out the [Dirichlet Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html).

Comment: @FD_bfa Please don't make purely cosmetic edits to (ten year) old postings. That puts then on the active question queue, where they distract from real new content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $\Bbb P\subseteq\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb P$ is infinite, it follows automatically that $|\Bbb P|=|\Bbb N|$: **every** infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$.

Suppose that $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ is infinite. Then we can recursively define a bijection $\varphi$ from $\Bbb N$ to $A$ by setting $$\varphi(n)=\min\big(A\setminus\{\varphi(k):k<n\}\big)\;:$$

$\Bbb N$ is well-ordered by $\le$ so $\min S$ is well-defined for any non-empty $S\subseteq\Bbb N$, and the hypothesis that $A$ is infinite ensures that $A\setminus\{\varphi(k):k<n\}\ne\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Peter: You must have commented while I was adding exactly that argument.

Comment: @Peter: There is no need to use the axiom of choice. If you have an injection into a well-ordered set, or a surjection from a well-ordered set, then things can be done constructively from those functions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I realized that later.

Answer (score 4):

In short $|\mathbb{P}| = \aleph_0$. There are infinitely many primes, and every prime is an integer. So the primes are a countably infinite set, just like $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. To put them in their place, consider the sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \, . $$

However, the sum of reciprocals $1/p$ where $p$ is prime, i.e. $1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/11 + \cdots $ actually *diverges*! So, in some sense, there are "more" primes than there are square numbers. In short: there are "less" primes than there are natural numbers, but "more" primes than there are square numbers.

Comment: Fewer? You mean more. Bigger sum, more summands.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Absolutely! Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: Nice argument. Can this notion of "more" and "less" be somehow formalized?

Comment: It is called the "asymptotic density" of a subset of $B$ of $\Bbb N$. I think it was discussed in here before. [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density). Bascially, one sets $B\cap \{1,\dots,n\}=B(n)$ and takes $\limsup |B(n)|/n$ and $\liminf |B(n)|/n$. As expected, the odds and evens have asymptotic density of $1/2$, and the squares, cubes, &c, $0$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I'm not sure that fits the bill. The asymptotic density of the primes is also zero. So in terms of this measure the primes and the squares are indistinguishable.

Comment: @dtldarek: You can define a "measure" on the natural numbers which assigns $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ the measure $\sum_{n\in A}\frac1n$ (assume $0\notin\mathbb N$ for that matter). I never sat to fully verify this but it seems that most of the axioms of a measure hold here. Then you can really say what's less and what's more.

Comment: Well, one can see there are "more" primes by noting that $n/p_n\sim 1/\log n$ whilst $n/s_n=1/n$; meaning that one goes faster to zero than the other.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But what happens to the sequences $(a_i)$ for which $\sum a_i^{-1}$ diverges? With this measure the primes and the natural numbers are indistinguishable.

Comment: @FlybyNight: In the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ are the full interval and the irrationals in it, and the complement of the Cantor set distinguishable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's not the point. The idea was to find a way to formalise "more" or "less". The pseudo-measure $(a_i) \mapsto \sum a_i^{-1}$ doesn't do that in the sense that it thinks that the primes and the squares are the same.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I think you're on to something here. How might we turn this idea into a measure?

Comment: @FlybyNight: But measure theory is a way of formalizing more and less. Exactly like how order theory can be used to do so, as well cardinality is a way to do so. I really don't see what's the issue with the fact that sets *could* have indistinguishable sizes. Also the way I suggested to measure the size of sets does differ between squares and primes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The OP's follow up question was how to make the idea that there are "more" primes than there are square formal. The pseudo-measure $(a_i) \mapsto \sum a_i^{-1}$ does not do that; it thinks there are the "same" number. Any measure that answer's the OP's follow up question must distinguish and must say there are more primes.

Comment: @FlybyNight: My comment was not to the OP. It was to dltdarek which asked something in the comments. If you really want to make it "better" use the measurement: $$\mu(A)=\frac6{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in A}\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant to say dltdarek. He said "*Nice argument. Can **this** notion of "more" and "less" be somehow formalized?*"

Comment: Well, from my perspective, it was kind of weird (but still strangely very intuitive) that if you sum up smaller set, you have smaller sum and thus some of those series might converge and others might not -- all of those have cardinality $\aleph_0$, right? There is a _bijection_ between naturals, primes and squares, and this means that the difference between those sizes should be a bit more subtle. For example if we were to represent sizes by tuples with lexicographic order, then all those would have something like $(\aleph_0, 1, 1, ...), (\aleph_0, 1, 0, ...), (\aleph_0, 0, 0, ...)$ etc. CTD.

Comment: CTD. Of course I am making this up. What is interesting, is if we can denote a sequence (it looks like it would have to be indexed by something similar to $\mathbb{Q}$ or even more complex) of series so that we would be able to distinguish between sizes of those sets. And _that_ maybe could be turned to some kind of pseudo-measure. There would be some series $(a_n)$ that would make converge $\sum a_n p_n$, but not $\sum a_n b_n$ wher $p_n$ are primes and $b_n$ are for example numbers with at most two factors. What do you think?

Comment: @dtldarek: If you don't mind ditching real numbers for ordinals, fix $\alpha$ some large enough countable ordinal (e.g. $\omega_1^{CK}$, or even larger) and let $\prec$ be an ordering of $\omega$ such that $(\omega,\prec)$ is of order type $\alpha$, and take the measure of $A$ to be the order type of the restriction of $\prec$ to $A$.

Comment: @dtldarek You can make the idea quite formal. Let $N_x(P)$ be the number of primes between $1$ and $x$. Moreover, let $N_x(S)$ be the number of squares. The prime number theorem tells us that $N_x(P) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$, while $N_x(S) = \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor \sim \sqrt{x}$. Here $f \sim g$ if $|f(x)/g(x)| \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$. Clearly $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ grows much faster than $\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

The primes are  subset of $\Bbb N$. But they are infinite. Since $\Bbb N$ is well ordered we can define an injection from $\Bbb P$ to $\Bbb N$ as follows. Let $p_1$ be the least element of $\Bbb P$. Let $p_2$ be the least element of $\Bbb P-\{p_1\}$ and in general let $p_{n+1}$ be the least element of $\Bbb P_n=\Bbb P-\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Then $n\mapsto p_n$ is a bijection. This works in the general case that $B$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem:** If $f\colon\mathbb N\to A$ is surjective then either $A$ is finite, or $|A|=|\mathbb N|$. Alternatively if $g\colon A\to\mathbb N$ is injective then the same conclusion about $A$ is true.

**Theorem:** The set of prime numbers is not finite.

**Corollary:** There are countably many prime numbers.

---

I should also add that there are not many formulas we can write, and there are many subsets to $\mathbb N$. The result is that almost all infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, while having the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$ do not have a "formulated bijection" between them.

I should add that if we are given the set then we can produce from that set the bijection, but this is already a parameter which we use in the formula.

For such bijection, see [If $X$ is an infinite set and there exists an injection $X \to \mathbb{N}$, is there also a bijection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/if-x-is-an-infinite-set-and-there-exists-an-injection-x-to-mathbbn-is-t/)